# Adding Image from specific folder like google photos App crashes using cropimage library

Tags: android, image, nullpointerexception, crop

I am using "eu.janmuller.android.simplecropimage" cropimage libarary.

I am getting following error while adding image from specific folder like google photos/any other folder other than gallery :

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{app.qourier/eu.janmuller.android.simplecropimage.CropImage}: java.lang.NullPointerException

Code:

```
public void openGallerywithraio() {
    String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ratio = 1;
    TEMP_PHOTO_FILE_NAME = "id.jpg";
    if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state)) {
        mFileTemp = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
                TEMP_PHOTO_FILE_NAME);
    } else {
        mFileTemp = new File(mActivity.getFilesDir(), TEMP_PHOTO_FILE_NAME);
    }
    // this.ratio = ratio;
    openGallery();
}

public void openGallery() {

    Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
            android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
    photoPickerIntent.setType("image/*");

    mActivity.startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent,
            REQUEST_CODE_GALLERY);

}
```

on Activity result  :

```
case REQUEST_CODE_GALLERY:
        System.out.println("On activity result===="+mFileTemp+"DATA===>"+data.getData());

        try {
            InputStream inputStream = mActivity.getContentResolver()
                    .openInputStream(data.getData());
            FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(
                    mFileTemp);
            copyStream(inputStream, fileOutputStream);
            fileOutputStream.close();
            inputStream.close();
            startCropImage(getgalleryrotation(mActivity));

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Error while creating temp file", e);
        }

        break;

private void startCropImage(int orientationInDegree) {

    //doCrop();
    int aspectX, aspectY, outputX, outputY;
    ScreenResolution sr = deviceDimensions();

    int gcd = GCD(sr.width, sr.height);
    aspectX = sr.width / gcd;
    aspectY = sr.height / gcd;
    // define the output image width & height possibly low as android
    // default crop is not well suited to pick big image :(
    outputX = sr.width - aspectX * 20;
    outputY = sr.height - aspectY * 20;

    System.out.println("Start corp image ===");
    Intent intent = new Intent(mActivity, CropImage.class);

    intent.putExtra(CropImage.IMAGE_PATH, mFileTemp.getPath());
    intent.putExtra(CropImage.SCALE, true);
    //indicate output X and Y

    System.out.println("RATIO DATATAAA==========>"+outputX+outputY+"ASPECT RATION:"+aspectX+aspectY);

    /*intent.putExtra(CropImage.ASPECT_X, 2);
    intent.putExtra(CropImage.ASPECT_Y, 1);*/
    if (ratio == 1) {
        System.out.println("RATIO DATATAAA==== IN 1======>"+ratio);
        intent.putExtra(CropImage.ASPECT_X, 1);
        intent.putExtra(CropImage.ASPECT_Y, 1);


    } else if (ratio == 0) {

        System.out.println("RATIO DATATAAA==== IN 0======>"+ratio);
        intent.putExtra(CropImage.CIRCLE_CROP, "true");

        intent.putExtra(CropImage.ASPECT_X, 1);
        intent.putExtra(CropImage.ASPECT_Y, 1);

    } else {

        /*intent.putExtra("outputX", outputX);
        intent.putExtra("outputY", outputY);*/
        System.out.println("RATIO DATATAAA==== IN ELSE======>"+ratio);
        intent.putExtra(CropImage.ASPECT_X, 2);
        intent.putExtra(CropImage.ASPECT_Y,1);


    }
    String size = getBitmap(mFileTemp.getPath());
    String[] str = size.split("_");
    System.out.println("SIZE");
    if(Integer.parseInt(str[0]) <= 10 || Integer.parseInt(str[1]) <= 10){

        Toast.makeText(mActivity, "Image size bellow 10 pixels Try another one", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }else{

        //System.out.println("RATIO DATATAAA AFTER==========>"+ratio);
        intent.putExtra(CropImage.ORIENTATION_IN_DEGREES, orientationInDegree);
        mActivity.startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE_CROP_IMAGE);
    }


}
public String getBitmap(String path) {

     File f = new File(path);

        // decode image size

        BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        o.inDither = false; // Disable Dithering mode

        o.inPurgeable = true; // Tell to gc that whether it needs free memory,
                                // the Bitmap can be cleared

        o.inInputShareable = true; // Which kind of reference will be used to
                                    // recover the Bitmap data after being
                                    // clear, when it will be used in the future
        try {
            BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f), null, o);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        // Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.
        final int REQUIRED_SIZE = 2048;
        int width_tmp = o.outWidth, height_tmp = o.outHeight;

        int scale = 1;
        while (true) {
            if (width_tmp / 1.5 < REQUIRED_SIZE && height_tmp / 1.5 < REQUIRED_SIZE)
                break;
            width_tmp /= 1.5;
            height_tmp /= 1.5;
            scale *= 1.5;
        }


        return width_tmp+"_"+height_tmp;
    }
```

Can you please help me out from this specific folder issue while adding image?

Thanks

Comment: show your code too

Comment: please post your code

Comment: ok pls check updated question